# Is it possible to set up a template for an Alembic .py upgrade script?

Tags: python, alembic

When I run `alembic revision -m '...'`, Alembic generates a new .py script with the default body looking like this:

```
from alembic import op

# revision identifiers, used by Alembic.
revision = '1ce7873ac4ced2'
down_revision = '1cea0ac4ced2'
branch_labels = None
depends_on = None


def upgrade():
    pass

def downgrade():
    pass
```

Is it possible for me to specify my own template for those two functions' body, `upgrade` and `downgrade`? I know that I could always write some sort of wrapper for this `alembic revision` command which would also substitute my desired function body for those two `pass` keywords, but I was wondering if there's an "alembic" way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question after a couple of days: I realized that `script.py.mako` file auto-generated in alembic's migration environment folder is essentially for this purpose of providing a template for migration scripts.